# php zend framework 2 routing with dynamic controller name but same controller

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

i'm running into a routing beginners problem with zend framework 2:
i want to make a routing that will work something like this:

> www.mysite.com/city/school/class

with the routing i want to be able:

> www.mysite.com/chicago

will take me to a city.phtml page with "chicago" as a parameter

same with

> www.mysite.com/chicago/jcc

will take me to a school.phtml with "jcc" as a parameter name

and so on..

what i tried to do is:

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'main' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '[/:city][/:school][/:class]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'city'      => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'school'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'class'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),

                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ...
```

but i don't have any idea how to continue from here :(

thanks!

Comment: How about using `GET` method here with parameters like school, city ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a couple of hours i got it working, hope this helps someone:

> ```
> 'router' => array(
>     'routes' => array(
>         'city' => array(
>             'type'    => 'Segment',
>             'options' => array(
>                 'route'    => '/main[/][:city]',
>                 'constraints' => array(
>                     'city'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
>                 ),
>                 'defaults' => array(
>                     '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Main\Controller',
>                     'controller'    => 'main',
>                     'action'        => 'city',
>                 ),
>             ),
>             'may_terminate' => true,
>             'child_routes' => array(
>                 'school' => array(
>                     'type'    => 'Segment',
>                     'options' => array(
>                         'route'    => '[/][:school]',
>                         'constraints' => array(
>                             'school' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
>                         ),
>                         'defaults' => array(
>                             '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Main\Controller',
>                             'controller'    => 'main',
>                             'action'        => 'school',
>                         ),
>                     ),
>                     'may_terminate' => true,
>                     'child_routes' => array(
>                         'class' => array(
>                             'type'    => 'Segment',
>                             'options' => array(
>                                 'route'    => '[/][:class]',
>                                 'constraints' => array(
>                                     'class' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
>                                 ),
>                                 'defaults' => array(
>                                     '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Main\Controller',
>                                     'controller'    => 'main',
>                                     'action'        => 'class',
>                                 ),
>                             ),
>                         ),
>                     ),
>                 ),
>             ),
>         ),
>     ),
> ),
> ```

so when calling

```
www.mysite.com/chicago
```

i am redirected to the city action and can get the chicago var in my controller by:

> $this->params()->fromRoute('city')