# I want to create dynamic routing for all the modules in zend framework 2.3?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-studio

I am newbie to Zend Framework 2.3 let's examine that i have multiple modules in my application in Zend framework 2.3 but i don't want create separate files for module configuration for routes i want to create dynamic routes so how can i perform it please help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771663/php-zend-framework-2-routing-with-dynamic-controller-name-but-same-controller

Comment: wildcard routes are considered bad practice. It is advised to use explicit routes instead

Comment: Take a look at this route in zend skeleton application, but remember it is not recommended approach: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L23

Answer (score 0):

A global route is what you want :

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'pages' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'       => '/:module/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                    'constraints' => array(

                        'module' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'         => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ),


                ),
            ), 

      ), 
 ),
```

Comment: Zf2 application have no concept of modules once it is bootstrapped.

Comment: @Xerkus doesn't matter, as long as the controllers have unique names